# what the differences between ndarray and list in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

last week, my teacher asks us: when storing integers from one to one hundred, what the differences between using **list** and using **ndarray**. I never use numpy before, so I search this question on the website.
But all my search result told me, they just have dimension difference. **Ndarray** can store N dimension data, while **list** storge one. That doesn't satisfy me. Is it really simple, just my overthinking, Or I didn't find the right keyword to search?
I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several differences:

-You can append elements to a list, but you can't change the size of a ´numpy.ndarray´ without making a full copy.

-Lists can containt about everything, in numpy arrays all the elements must have the same type.

-In practice, numpy arrays are faster for vectorial functions than mapping functions to lists.

-I think than modification times is not an issue, but iteration over the elements is.
Numpy arrays have many array related methods (´argmin´, ´min´, ´sort´, etc).

I prefer to use numpy arrays when I need to do some mathematical operations (sum, average, array multiplication, etc) and list when I need to iterate in 'items' (strings, files, etc).

Answer (score 2):

### A ***one-dimensional array*** is like ***one*** row graph paper .##

[image]

### You can store one thing inside of each box

[image: PHOTO OF A SECOND EXAMPLE OF A ONE DIMENTIONAL ARRAY]

### The following picture is an example of a ***2-dimensional array***

[image: TWO DIMENSIONAL ARRAY]

#### Two-dimensional arrays have rows and columns

I should have changed the numbers.
When I was drawing the picture I just copied the first row many times.
The numbers can be completely different on each row.

```python
import numpy as np

lol = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
# `lol` is a list of lists

arr_har = np.array(lol, np.int32)

print(type(arr_har)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print("BEFORE:")
print(arr_har)

# change the value in row 0 and column 2.
arr_har[0][2] = 999

print("\n\nAFTER arr_har[0][2] = 999:")
print(arr_har)
```

### The following picture is an example of a ***3-dimensional array***

[image: THREE_DIMENSIONAL_ARRAY]

## Summary/Conclusion:

#### A `list` in Python acts like a ***one-dimensional array.***

#### `ndarray` is an abbreviation of "n-dimensional array" or "multi-dimensional array"

#### The difference between a Python `list` and an `ndarray`, is that an ndarray has 2 or more dimensions

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my poor English makes my question confusing. What I mean is that I search this question on the internet, only find this difference, like your answer. I try finding other differences, like the other answer in this question said. Thanks anyway!